# Handlebar examples in Apache Superset

Tags: handlebars.js, apache-superset

I am trying to use handlebar chart in my Superset dashboard but somehow not able to get it work as I would like to.

I have a column in data which I want to format as per data. E.g. if the data is high, I need background to be RED and may be a small upper arrow - could be an image. And same some formatting for medium and low values.

How do I do it, can someone help with some example and CSS formatting to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic in SQL as a virtual column, call it say "HighValue", something like:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (DATA > XX) THEN true
  ELSE false
END
```

In your Handlebars chart, put a check with

```
{{#if HighValue}}
Put your HTML and CSS here for high value. You can use SVG for the arrows
{{else}}
Put HTML and CSS here for low value
{{/if}}
```

You can use classes and then put the colors etc. in the CSS rather than inline.